# How do we actually use urelements, in practice? Example request.

Tags: set-theory

In the usual approach to ordinals and cardinals (namely, von Neumann's approach), every cardinal is also an ordinal, and every ordinal is also a set. So if $\kappa$ is a cardinal, then the expression $2^\kappa$ has at least three meanings; so its meaning has to be specified in the surrounding text, or inferred from the context.

Now arguably, this isn't an issue of any real substance. That's a perfectly legitimate position; I don't happen to share it. For that reason, I'd like to experiment with the idea that *set*, *ordinal* and *cardinal* are mutually exclusive concepts. That way, if $\kappa$ is a cardinal, then expressions like $2^\kappa$ are unambiguous - e.g. in this case, its definitely cardinal exponentiation we're doing.

To give another example, there's good reason to distinguish between Conway's implementation of the surreal numbers, and the surreal numbers themselves. Otherwise, statements like $x=y$ are ambiguous - do we mean they're equal as numbers, or that they're equal as sets?

So we now have two reasons to distinguish between entities and the sets that represent them. The first was the ambiguity of expressions like $2^\kappa$. The second is the ambiguity of statements like $x=y$.

Lets focus our attention on the surreal numbers as an example. Suppose for a moment that we're sold on the above arguments. In this hypothetical universe, we want to distinguish between Conway's implementation of the surreal numbers, and the surreal numbers themselves.

Okay, one way of doing this would be to conservatively extend our language with new sorts. So we start off with a one sorted language whose elements are called 'sets.' Then we define a proper class $C$ whose elements are precisely the sets that Conway calls 'surreal numbers,' as well as an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $C$ that specifies which elements of $C$ are identical as numbers.

Now here comes the unconventional part. Instead of stopping there, we go one step further by extending our language with a new sort $S$ whose elements are called 'surreal numbers', and a canonical function $C \rightarrow S$ such that if $f$ is the aforementioned function, then $x \sim y \Leftrightarrow f(x)=f(y)$ for all $x,y \in C$.

It seems great in theory, but there's a problem: we can't collect surreal numbers into sets. After all, $\in$ is a relationship between two sets, so if $\alpha$ is a surreal number, then '$\alpha \in X$' isn't even a well-formed expression! Clearly, this isn't convenient.

**Question.** Can the approach using sorts be salvaged? If so, how?

I hope its salvageable, but lets assume for the moment that it isn't, or that no one knows how. Then we need another approach.

Enter the atom (or [urelement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urelement), if you prefer). We begin the same: define $C$ and $\sim$. But, instead of adding a new sort $S$, we just collect a bunch of atoms together into a class, call it $S$ for 'surreal numbers.' Since atoms can belong to sets, concepts like $\alpha \in X$ make sense, *even if $\alpha$ is surreal*. Yay! We've solved the problem. That's the theory, but I've never actually seen this done in practice. What does it actually look like? Thus, I have a request.

**Request.** Can someone write up an example of how this would be done, in practice? I get the general gist of the idea, but I'm unsure about the details.

Comment: The point in having cardinals and ordinals and sets is that we don't need more than $\in$ and a few axioms in order to express **everything**. It's fine to define new types, but that'd be missing the idea of set theory. It's not about being nitpicky and pedantic, it's about rejecting set theory and accepting type theory. That's perfectly reasonable.

Comment: I downvoted because the first paragraph is somewhat condescending by telling me what to read or not to read. If you would edit it, I'll be happy to remove my downvote.

Comment: The other option, if I can be so bold, would be to typographically differentiate between the different meanings.  Something like $\kappa^\lambda$ for cardinal exponentiation, $\kappa^{\cdot \lambda}$ for ordinal exponentiation, and ${^\lambda} \kappa$ for the set of all functions $\lambda \to \kappa$.

Comment: @Asaf, i didnt mean to be condescending. Im not at my computer anymore so it would be a real pain to edit it at the moment, but I'll change it when i get the chance.

Comment: Also, note that this sort of trade off appears everywhere in mathematics. You can't remove it, because people are like that. People prefer the "shortcuts" that everyone in a given field easily fill in the gaps, rather than tediously work and make sure that *everyone* outside their field can fully understand everything. If Shelah were to write for the layman (or even the lay-set theorist), he wouldn't have had that much work done...

Comment: @user18921: There's no real rush, just wanted to point this out.

Comment: @Arthur: And as many of Shelah's paper begin with notational conventions: $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ denote ordinals, $\delta$ is always a limit ordinal; $\kappa,\lambda,\mu,\nu$ denote cardinals; ...

Comment: @Asaf thanks, ill deal with it when I get the chance.

Comment: It seems that you just have an issue with the standard notation, and that this really isn't an issue of any mathematical substance. Why go through all of this trouble when we can just use Arthur Fischer's suggestion and distinguish between the different kinds of exponentiation typographically?

Comment: @AsafKaragila, okay how about now?

Comment: Yeah, much better. But it's von Neumann, rather than Von Neumann.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, fixed. Btw, I'd like to try my hand at rebutting your first comment here, if you're interested in a chat.

Comment: I am not using the chat system on the site. If you want to discuss this in the comments, then it's fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I completely disagree with this approach, but let me give my opinion on how it should be done.

The problem with atoms is that they are completely indiscernible from one another. If $a,b$ are atoms and $\varphi(a)$ is true then $\varphi(b)$ is true as well. At least in the language where all we have to express is $\in$ which is a relation pertaining sets and their elements.

This is why you ought to be adding two things. The class of atoms and an ordering on the atoms. Then you can add an axiom stating that the atoms and their ordering is a well-order class isomorphic to the usual class of ordinals. Then you can declare that from now on we shall refer to these atoms when we talk about ordinals.

Similarly we add a third sort for cardinals, and we can include the order or addition/multiplication into the language.

But the point is that there are no theorems which will be stated differently. Just whenever we refer to ordinals it will be clear that these ordinals have a different type than the rest of the sets. Of course we have to tweak a lot of definitions, for example a sequence of length $\alpha$ is no longer a function from the ordinal $\alpha$, but rather a function whose domain is $\{x\in{\sf Ord^*}\mid x<\alpha\}$. And so on and so forth. But beyond these sort of tweaks and changes there shouldn't be any change whatsoever. The only difference is that now when you say "Let $\alpha,\beta$ be two ordinals and $\gamma=\alpha+\beta$" we know that this cannot be addition as cardinals or anything because ordinals make a completely different type of object.

This is a particularly good time to bring up (again) the point that in set theory we really write meta-proofs rather than proofs. That is, we actually say "suppose that $\varphi(x,y,z)$ is the formula stating that $z$ is the ordered pair $\langle x,y\rangle$, then bla bla bla".

We don't *really* care about the formula. It's quite easy to take Kuratowski's definition for ordered pairs, but there are others. We just care about the fact that such definition exists and it's simple enough. Rarely we *do* care that the encoding is simple enough, but even then there are degrees of freedom.

Similarly we don't *really* care about the actual way of devising ordinals or cardinals, and all our proofs can be easily re-fitted to any definitions of these mathematical notions. But sometimes it makes things simpler that way, so it's more convenient to just use it like that. Of course when we have the von Neumann ordinals then often we can make nice shortcuts (such as the aforementioned about sequences), but it's not very difficult seeing that this is not a real mathematical issue. In fact, I doubt that *you* would find it confusing too.

Comment: A comment on your last sentence: its not about me! Its about pedagogy, and general accessibility. Anyway, thank you for your answer.

Comment: Sadly mathematics is not about accessibility for *everyone*. It is about mathematics. And it is very convenient to have these things, just as much as it is convenient to have small "holes" in other fields that would make them inaccessible. People who want to understand the results of set theory will study set theory. If you insist on making things readable you will inevitably complicate them to a point they are unreadable by *anyone*. At least now a set theorist can (theoretically) read most set theory texts, even if they do have some confusing parts.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're saying, but I think you're suggesting that, "the most important thing is mathematical progress." That's probably true, but note that most fields do indeed organize their subject matter by defining functions between sets of objects whose internal structure remains undefined. This doesn't seem to hamper the people in those fields - so why should it hamper progress in set theory?

Comment: I'm saying even more than that. I'm saying that most of those people are uninterested in set theory to begin with. If they are uninterested, why should we bother to accommodate them?

Comment: You shouldn't. But if they ARE interested, you should reward their interest by maximizing the return/effort ratio. Not at the price of undermining mathematical progress of course. Anyway, I didn't mean my original question to be specifically about set theory for the sake of set theory. It was meant to be about set theory for the sake of studying various other number systems. I chose the ordinals and cardinals because they're well-known and the issue of ambiguity actually comes up in practice, rather than just in theory, but the question could easily have been about the reals or surreals.

Comment: And I think you'll find people are very, very interested in number systems in general.

Comment: That's so much easier to fix. Let $S$ denote a number system, then $+_S$ and $\cdot_S$ denote its operations. If one is so inclined then $(x^y)_S$ can denote exponentiation. This is just what we do when we work with several fields or rings or groups or whatever that are incompatible with one another.

Comment: Yes. I've toyed with that solution, however, I think you'll  find that its impractical. Readability just plumets as soon as those subscripts show up. *Edit.* Anyway, doing it with functions saves us asking bad questions. In the current approach, we must currently ask ourselves, 'what's the best canonical representative of this concept?' Using functions alleviates this issue to some extent.

Comment: Requiring the read to store in mind all the types and their different properties, and at the same time taking away the little shortcuts (e.g. $\alpha<\beta\iff\alpha\in\beta$ for ordinals, and using them as sets all of a sudden) is just cruel. :-)

Comment: In retrospect, I shouldn't have brought ordinals into the question. They're one of the few cases where confounding an abstract entity with its set-theoretic representation is really, really convenient.

Comment: Well, tough luck. :-)

Comment: There's a few more points I'd like to bring up. Firstly, type theory is less convenient than set theory, in my opinion. For instance, if I have a set $X$ and two others $Y_0,Y_1$, and a pair of functions $f_0 : X \rightarrow Y_0$ and $f_1 : X \rightarrow Y_1,$ then the entity $\{f_0,f_1\}$ makes no sense in type theory. So, I don't *want* to abandon set theory and adopt type theory. It would be like abandoning automobiles because there's too much traffic - I'd rather drive to work half an hour earlier.

Comment: Which brings me to my second point. What I want is not a different foundations. I don't want type theory, or SEAR, or ETCS. No. I want ZFC, or a variant thereof. I want set theory. And yes, I'd like to use set theory in a slightly unconventional way. So? All progress depends on taking a risk, doing the unconventional, and seeing the results. I'm not arguing everybody should suddenly drop what they're doing and start talking about atoms. I'm saying, "I want to try this out. Can anyone show me, rigorously, how to try it out? Because I'm stumped."

Comment: I don't get it. You agree that set theory make a good foundations for mathematics, but then you feel that it's too ambiguous and we need to extend it some more? Do you know why set theory with urelements didn't stick? Because its consistency strength is the same as set theory without urelements. People look for minimality, in some sense. At least those looking for set theory as a foundation. Adding new types of objects sounds... wrong.

Comment: Look if we're talking about models of set theory and doing forcing, allowing for the possibility of atoms just complicates things. But if we're using set theory to found other branches of mathematics, then yes, I think its likely that the best way to do this is with atoms. I'm not hardcore committed to the idea, but I just want to experiment with it.

Comment: So, you have decided the truth value of the continuum hypothesis, the Whitehead problem, and many other problems which turn out to be independent of $\sf ZFC$? :-)

Comment: Huh? $\qquad\!\!\!\!$

Comment: All those non-contrived questions which turn out independent of $\sf ZFC$, and forcing was somewhat essential in the proof of their independence. If you don't care about forcing then you at least have to decide on a universe and therefore decide the truth value of some things.

Comment: I'm not saying I don't care about forcing.... Why would you infer that?

Comment: Two reasons: The first is beer; the second is that you said "if we're talking about models of set theory and doing forcing, allowing for the possibility of atoms just complicates things. But if we're using set theory to found other branches of mathematics, then yes, I think its likely that the best way to do this is with atoms." which make it sound as if being interested in forcing is somewhat orthogonal to being interested in foundations.

Comment: What brand beer? Since the extensions with new sorts ought to be conservative, you should be able to do forcing with a pure set theory but nonetheless be able to draw conclusions about impure set theory with multiple sorts. I don't know the details.

Comment: Tuborg Red, but it's a local brew which fits the Israeli palate better, there was some noon event in my local pub. But the more important is that forcing doesn't add ordinals, sure. But forcing may very well change cardinals. Not to mention that forcing over the pure sets would add sets of atoms (because forcing usually adds sets of ordinals), so things become immensely more complicated. True, forcing over atoms is doable, but why? If you can get away without atoms and have forcing for free?

Comment: Shame, I like trying new beers. Anyway, I don't know enough about forcing to be able to answer that. But I'll bet that, if you look at it the right way, atoms don't add any serious complications.

Comment: I just realized something. If we want to view ordinals as non-sets, this doesn't necessarily prevent ordinals having elements. There's no reason we can't have $3 \in 5,$ so long as we allow atoms to have elements (in which case, probably best not to call them atoms. Better to call them 'non-sets'.)

Comment: @user18921: That's fine, but it sort of misses the philosophical point that objects which have elements are sets.

Comment: I'm impressed you managed to cram, 'sort', 'point', 'object', 'element' and 'set' all into one sentence. Ahem. Anyway I am not so sure that that philosophical point should be taken too seriously. |Convenience|>|Philosophy|, where |*| is the function that returns the importance of an entity.

Comment: It's a proof to how great I am. ;-) But more seriously, you'd be surprised how far people will go to satisfy their philosophy before they will settle for something more convenient.

Comment: Looks like you're going to win this one. Good thing too, because you TOTALLY need more reputation. ;)

Comment: @user18921: It sure does. I'm willing to bequeath these 50 points to an answer of your choice at any later point of time.

Comment: Nah its cool. If an exemplary answer is posted, I'd be more than happy to start another bounty just to award it. Accumulating rep points isnt really important to me, although I like getting +1's to my questions is nice because it confirms in my mind that I haven't asked a bad question.